# Duas arrays idênticas retornando false quando comparadas

Tags: javascript, comparação

Preciso de ajuda com este código que parece não fazer sentido.
Já debuguei e os valores dados até a penúltima linha são:

```
splited = ["i","s","o","g","r","a","m"]

unique = ["i","s","o","g","r","a","m"]
```

---

```
str = 'isogram'
var splited = str.split('');
let unique = [...new Set(splited)];
if(splited == unique){return true} else {return false}; // retorna false
```

Comment: arrays são objetos, não são iguais, são parecidos, assim como duas laranjas são parecidas.., o que você comparar no array pra ver se ele é igual é o seu tamanho e conteúdo

Comment: Cada vez que você está comparando dois arrays, na verdade está compararando a referencia na memória de ambos, portanto, sempre vai dar 'false'. Pois são duas instâncias diferentes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você trabalha com Arrays e Objetos, tenha em mente que você manipula sempre uma referência da variável, e não o valor dela em si. Vou deixar aqui em baixo um artigo explicando:

https://braziljs.org/artigos/diferencas-entre-valor-e-referencia-em-javascript/

Para comparar array, utilize o seguinte código:

**Função:**

```
// Warn if overriding existing method
if(Array.prototype.equals)
    console.warn("Overriding existing Array.prototype.equals. Possible causes: New API defines the method, there's a framework conflict or you've got double inclusions in your code.");
// attach the .equals method to Array's prototype to call it on any array
Array.prototype.equals = function (array) {
    // if the other array is a falsy value, return
    if (!array)
        return false;

    // compare lengths - can save a lot of time 
    if (this.length != array.length)
        return false;

    for (var i = 0, l=this.length; i < l; i++) {
        // Check if we have nested arrays
        if (this[i] instanceof Array && array[i] instanceof Array) {
            // recurse into the nested arrays
            if (!this[i].equals(array[i]))
                return false;       
        }           
        else if (this[i] != array[i]) { 
            // Warning - two different object instances will never be equal: {x:20} != {x:20}
            return false;   
        }           
    }       
    return true;
}
// Hide method from for-in loops
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "equals", {enumerable: false});
```

**Utilização:**

```
[1, 2, [3, 4]].equals([1, 2, [3, 2]]) === false;
[1, "2,3"].equals([1, 2, 3]) === false;
[1, 2, [3, 4]].equals([1, 2, [3, 4]]) === true;
[1, 2, 1, 2].equals([1, 2, 1, 2]) === true;
```

**Referência:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Answer (score -1):

Quando trabalha com Array o correto e sempre ver o length então você poderia fazer a seguinte comparação:

```
splited.length == unique.length  (true)
```

Comment: Também é necessário comparar o conteúdo, pois a condição: "[1, 2, 3].length === [4, 5, 6].length" retornaria true